# Making A Triangle With For Loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, geometry

```
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            cout<<"$";
        }

        cout<<"\n";
    }
```

The code shows a right triangle, but I need to modify it to get a complete triangle. I can't post the shape, but I need to modify the code in order to make something like this >. In other words I need to modify this code to flip the right triangle and connect it to the one I have and make a complete one.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be adding a second loop that goes down from `2` to `0`:

```
// Your first loop goes here
// After that, use this second loop:
for(int i=2;i>=0;i--)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        cout<<"$";
    }

    cout<<"\n";
}
```

This [prints](http://ideone.com/c35rwh) a triangle that looks like this:

```
$
$$
$$$
$$$$
$$$
$$
$
```